# How do I do a or select when using subsonic?

Tags: c#, subsonic

Here is my code:

```
TransactionCollection transactions = new TransactionCollection();
transactions.Where("next_action", "RESEND");
transactions.Where("job_id", CurrentJob.Id);
transactions.Load();
```

I really want it to say next_action is RESEND or next_action is TARGET.  Thanks.

Basically I want a select statemnt like this:

```
select * from transactions where job_id = 1 and (next_action = 'RESEND' OR next_action = 'TARGET');
```

or

```
select * from transactions where job_id = 1 and next_action IN ('RESEND', 'TARGET');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're on SubSonic version 2.1 or above you can take advantage of the AndExpression and OrExpression. For your first example the following should work:

```
TransactionCollection transactions = DB.Select().From(Transaction.Schema)
  .Where("job_id", CurrentJob.Id);
  .AndExpression("next_action")IsEqualTo("RESEND")
  .Or("next_action")IsEqualTo("TARGET")
  .ExecuteCollection<TransactionCollection>()
```

Comment: Have a  look at http://subsonicproject.com/querying/select-queries/ for more examples